# Unexpected token import, can not set up ES6 in my JS project with Mocha, Chai and Sinon

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to set up a simple ES6 project to play with mocha, chai and sinon in the Terminal. But whenever I try to `npm run test`, I keep getting an error:

```
/Users/UserName/workspace/UnitTesting/mocha-sinon-chai/src/App.spec.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import should from "chai";
                                                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

### Here are my:

**1. Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "mocha-sinon-chai",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "sinon": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "mocha": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib",
    "test": "mocha ./tests/*.spec.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**2. .babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

**3. Root folder structure:**

[image]

**4. App.spec.js:**

```
import should from "chai";
import { findOne } from "../src/App.js";

describe("App.js", function() {
  it("should return true if predicate exists in the array", function() {
    findOne([1, 2, 3], 3).should().be.true;
  });
});
```

**5. index.js** is empty
**6. App.js** simply contains a normal JS function

I have checked many other similar issues here on Stackoverflow and GitHub and none of those solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this `--require babel-core/register` to test script inside package.json solved the problem:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib",
    "test": "mocha ./tests/*.spec.js --require babel-core/register"
  },
```